# Need algorithm to protect string with password?

Tags: java, passwords, password-protection

I am looking for a simple and FAST algorithm to encrypt/decrypt a string (length is about 128 bytes) with a password.

Any good algorithms?

ADDED: Custom algorithm is absolutely OK. Less memory it take - better it is (for my case). No extra classes - perfect.

Comment: Simple, fast, secure.  Pick two?  Okay, so maybe that's not quite accurate... but if your ONLY requirements are "simple" and "fast", us ROT13, or XOR.  Or reverse().  Surely you have greater requirements than this, though!

Comment: If the String is only 128 bytes long why do you need a fast algorithm?

Comment: 2 Fimzy - I pick Simple and Fast. I wrote about in in the topic :-)

Comment: 2 Dave Webb, I want to do millions of iterations and it is for OLTP platform.

Comment: 2 Flimzy: shame to ask, but - do you know any good library with XOR implemented?

Comment: I'm curious, if strength of protection is not an issue, only speed - why encrypt at all? Illusion of safety is often worse than no safety. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple encryption/decryption method. It is pretty weak, so I present it for, say *education purpose*:

```
    public static String encDec(String input, String password) {

      byte[] in = input.getBytes();
      byte[] key = password.getBytes();
      byte[] result = new byte[in.length];
      int k = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
         result[i] = (byte)(in[i] ^ key[k]);
         k++;
         if (k == key.length) 
           k=0;
      }

      return new String(result);
    }
```

It simply xors the bytes of a phrase with the bytes of a password. The same method can be used to encrypt and decrypt. Not a big challenge for a crypto analyst, by the way, but an easy start if you just need to *obfuscate* some data.

To make it a slightly better: don't pass a *password String* but a byte array with random values. But you wanted a method with a password, that's why I've implemented it *that* way ;)

Comment: Thank you! I really need to obfuscate some data. Nothing else. Thank you again :)

Comment: If you choose spaces as your password, lower case text will just get uppercased.

Comment: (Was that downvote the long expected *everything below AES is a bad answer* reflex? If *yes*, dear downvoter, please study the warnings in my answer, if not please leave a comment)

Answer (score 3):

[`AES Algorithm`](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)  : [`Implementation`](http://lkamal.blogspot.com/2009/10/java-encrypt-decrypt-jce-salt.html)

> AES is a federal standard for
>   private-key or symmetric cryptography.
>   It supports combinations of key and
>   block sizes of 128, 192, and 256.

---

How about [`IDEA - International Data 
Encryption Algorithm`](http://www.thehackademy.net/madchat/crypto/papers/IDEA_0304.pdf)  ?

> IDEA is the name of the patented and
>   universally applicable block 
>   encryption algorithm, which permits
>   the effective protection of 
>   transmitted and stored data against
>   unauthorized access by third  parties.

See for the implementation : [`How to implement IDEA?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541729/how-to-implement-idea)

Comment: 2 saugok: One vote up for pointing AES. I know about it, but it is not for my case, because I need very fast algorithm. Main point is simplicity and speed, not security.

Comment: But AES failed in simple and FAST algorithm requirement

Answer (score 1):

AES or 3DES are pretty "standard" symmetrical key encryptions. Blowfish is another.

Check http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html for using AES with Java, for instance.

Side note: If this is intended for securing something like passwords, you should really use a one-way hashing method instead (like MD5 or similar). Unless you absolutely have to be able to decrypt the text, one-way hashing is much safer. When, for instance, storing passwords in a database you would hash the password (with something like MD5) and store it. Validating a login is then done by hashing the user input and comparing it with the hashed value stored in the database.

Comment: 2 pap, Thank you for your answer, but it is not for my case.

Answer (score 1):

See [Java Crypto!](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/package-summary.html) for `Encryption and Decryption`

Answer (score 1):

There is the Tiny Encryption Algorithm ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXTEA ).

It's pretty simple and fast (for an encryption algorithm) and there are Java implementations.